# Use moment with Vue.js and return the date as UTC

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-table

I have a component that lists all the tasks.

When I create a task I want to show the date of creation on the added task and I want to list all the tasks.

The issue is all the tasks dates are converted to datetime now UTC.

```js
    <template>
      <div class="tasks-wrapper">
        <div class="tasks-header">
          <h4>{{ $t('client.taskListingTitle') }}</h4>
          <b-button variant="custom" @click="showAddTaskModal">{{ $t('client.addTask') }}</b-button>
        </div>
          <b-table
            striped
            hover
            :items="tasks"
            :fields="fields"
            show-empty
            :empty-text="$t('common.noResultsFound')">
            <template #cell(createdOn)="data">
              {{ formatDate(data.createdOn) }}
            </template>
          </b-table>
        <AddTaskModal />
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
    import AddTaskModal from '@/components/modals/AddTaskModal'
    import moment from 'moment'
    
    export default {
      name: 'TaskListing',
      components: {
        AddTaskModal
      },
      data () {
        return {
          tasks: [],
          fields: [
            { key: 'createdOn', label: this.$t('tasks.tableFields.date'), formatter: 'formatDate' },
            { key: 'domain', label: this.$t('tasks.tableFields.task') },
            { key: 'comment', label: this.$t('tasks.tableFields.comment') },
            { key: 'status', label: this.$t('tasks.tableFields.status') }
          ]
        }
      },
      computed: {
        ...mapGetters('users', ['user'])
      },
      methods: {
        ...mapActions('tasks', ['fetchTasks']),
        ...mapActions('users', ['fetchUserById']),
        formatDate: function (date) {
          return moment(date).utc(true).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm')
        },
        showAddTaskModal () {
          this.$bvModal.show('addTaskModal')
        }
      },
      async mounted () {
        const currUserId = this.$router.history.current.params.id
        if (this.user || this.user.userId !== currUserId) {
          await this.fetchUserById(currUserId)
        }
        if (this.user.clientNumber !== null) {
          const filters = { clientReferenceNumber: { value: this.user.clientNumber } }
          this.tasks = await this.fetchTasks({ filters })
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

If I delete this:

```html
       <template #cell(createdOn)="data">
          {{ formatDate(data.createdOn) }}
        </template>
```

the dates are displayed correctly on the task lists, however, when a task is added an Invalid Date is shown. I need to refresh the page of it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try with : `return moment(date).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm')` as your `formatDate` method ?

Comment: What is the value of `data.createdOn` when a task is added?

Comment: tony19 when task is added, data.createdOn is undefined because the response does not return it. You get createdOn when you fetch all tasks. Right now only way of fixing this is making another query to fetch all tasks after the new task has been created..